# dotnet pack multi-project templates created using template.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, template-engine

I recently watched a dotnet core [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hTkC02kaik&list=PLEjAdoHtpRSbOKDwsuAzpocf_R3igAads) that shows you how to create project templates using the new templating engine. In the video it shows you that you can use a template.json file to make your project into a project template. You can also create a multi-project template just by altering the location of the template.json.

**Project Template Structure**

```
.
└── Template
    ├── .template.config
    │   └── template.json
    ├── Program.cs
    └── Template.csproj
```

**Mult-project folder structure**

```
.
├── .template.config
│   └── template.json
├── Template
│   ├── Program.cs
│   └── Template.csproj
└── Template.tests
    ├── Template.tests.csproj
    └── UnitTest1.cs
```

with either of these structures I can install the templates from a local folder with the following command.

`dotnet new -i /Path/To/CsprojFolderOrSolutionFolder`

This will add the project to the list of options that can be created with the dotnet new command. I am able to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-template-pack) to create a csproj file and modify it for a template pack. It will create the nuget back successfully but it will not install with the dotnet new install with the following command.

`dotnet new -i /Path/To/.nupkg`

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your package you created is in the **nupkg** folder and you named the package **My.Cool.PackageName.1.0.0.1.nupkg** this should work?

```
dotnet new -i "nupkg\My.Cool.PackageName.1.0.0.1.nupkg"
```

That means that your example has a missing package name?